# Fluent interface builder

Tags: javascript, fluent-interface

I'm working on a fluent interface builder that takes:

- an array of strings, each of which becomes a key to an object that is a function that follows the fluent interface pattern
- a terminator function which when called breaks the chain and does something else

I'm looking for some advice on how to improve this.

```
var Twitter = require('twit');

var secrets = require("./secrets/secrets");
var fs = require("fs");
var Twit = require('twit')

    var T = new Twit({
      consumer_key: secrets.consumer_key,
      consumer_secret: secrets.consumer_secret,
      access_token: secrets.access_token,
      access_token_secret: secrets.access_token_secret,
      timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,  // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
    });
    function fluentBuilder(options, terminator) {
      let locals = options.reduce((opt, e) => {
        opt[e] = null;
        return opt;
      }, {});
      var methods = options.reduce((opt, e) => {
        opt[e] = (val) => {
          if (val) {
            locals[e] = val;
            return opt;
          } else return locals[e];

        }
        return opt;
      }, {});
      methods.locals = locals;
      methods["execute"] = terminator;
      return methods;
    }

    var geocode = fluentBuilder(["lat", "long"],
      function () {
        var self = this;
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          T.get("geo/reverse_geocode", self.locals, function (err, data, results) {
            resolve(data);
          });
        });
      });
      //calls to lat and long are stored on the self.locals variable which is passed to the Promise callback.
      geocode.lat("34.0406")
        .long("-84.2031")
        .execute()
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
        });
```

Comment: Can you post some example code using this fluent interface?

Comment: Also, can you edit your title to describe what this fluent interface is trying to accomplish (e.g. fluent interface for creating google maps)?

Comment: the call back here makes a post to the twitter geocode API, but the terminator function can be anything.  The idea is to allow n number of parameters to be set (with n being the length of the array), capture these values in `self.locals` and when the user calls execute all of the parameters that have been set via the calls (lat, long) are passed into the callback.

Comment: the geocode.lat("34").long("-84") creates a `self.locals` variable of `{lat: 34, long: 84}`.

Comment: this is good information. Can you please add it to your code review?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a lot of complexity for limited/no value. Could you not just pass an object literal like `{lat: 34, long: 84}` to the geocoding function and be done with it, losing like 20 lines of code in the process?

A few other thoughts:

- Why are you requiring the same dependency twice under different names?
- Typically, javascript programmers like to use initial lowercase camel case.  You have several variables named starting with capital letters which may not be desirable.
- You have inconsistent use of `let` vs. `var` in `fluentBuilder`. Why have `locals` defined with `let` and `methods` defined with `var` when both variables are used within the same scope and there is no "inner" code block to which you are trying to limit visibility of `locals`.  Either one works exactly the same in this case, but it would be good to be consistent.
- Your indentation is inconsistent.
- Why does `fluentBuilder` return `methods`?